# Should i use xml or sql to store many bits of object info?

Tags: sql, xml

i have to store a number bits of information about store items for my website,
things such as title,src,links,stock,price,description,etc. I would use sql but i feel like there is to many bits and pieces of info so storing that info inside an xml file seems to be more appropriate choice. any help?

Comment: okay before i get down voted more, isnt the idea of using xml to describe alot of data which would be perfect for parsing and use (why not just use sql and create individual columns holding the information.. so why). i understand that its used for information transferring but why go through the trouble to save the data in a sql database with specific column names to then be transfered to xml? why? is it JUST to make information more accessible to all platforms or could u also store data there?

Comment: XML is nice because it is human readable and can be easily edited.  Storing XML in a database take up a lot more space than just saving data as fields.   if you plan to save data I would recommend  a database in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the possibilities to search your SQL table for specific data. If not needed now, you'll want to keep that option open for the future.

The work of creating the columns, and insert/update statements can be simplified by a script that generates the statements for these operations.

Storing the data as XML in one column makes your database design non-compliant with the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Normalising your database will lead to better performance, and fewer data consistency problems.

In your particular example, it seems that the data in the XML has multiple levels, with price and description data, probably per product. What if you need to change a product description? Think of the enormous find and replace you'd have to do in many records...

Don't hesitate: [normalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. Once it's set up, you'll not regret it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries for both. Whatever you are comfortable with you can use either one. Both methods (SQL & XML) work well. The decision depends on other factors too. For example, I have given my preference on the side

Is the data Static?         XML
Does the data volume (# of records) increase/decrease?   SQL
If it is a web app and the dataset is small, do you want to send the entire dataset to the frontend? XML
Adding new columns wouldn't make much of a difference either way. Lot of configuration data is stored in XML. But data the developer do not have control over, generally goes to a database. My 2 cents.....